# Dual Authentication in Webex: SSO and ID/Password

Tags: webex

I have a question about setting up SSO in webex.
Is there an option to also support ID/Password authentication in case the IdP(Azure AD etc..) goes down due to a failure?
I could not find such a setting in the Webex Control Hub.